CS50 : Tideman : sort_pairs
sort_pairs is not returning successfully when I check the code. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I spent quite a while on the previous functions getting them correct as I've been away from programming for a very long time...
Vote, record_preferences, add_pairs, those all get the green light. I do not understand where I'm going wrong with this simple code relative to the black box of how it's being checked.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
} pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
//DONE
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(candidates[i], name) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
// DONE
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    //sequence through ranks[] array
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        //compare i-th locations in ranks[] to determine ranking
        for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if((i < j) && (i != j))
            {
                preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]++;
            }

            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
// DONE
void add_pairs(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
          if(preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count++;
            }
            else if(preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = j;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = i;
                pair_count++;
            }
        }

    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    // Initialize variables and arrays for sorting
    int max = 0;
    int loc = 0;
    pair temp[1];
    // Selection sort pairs
    for(int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        max = preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser];
        for(int j = i; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            if(preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] > max)
            {
                max = preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser];
                loc = j;
            }
        }
        temp[0] = pairs[i];
        pairs[i] = pairs[loc];
        pairs[loc] = temp[0];
        printf("%i\n", pairs[i].winner);
    }
}


"Having trouble": that sounds quite vague... Please provide code that initialises the variables that are used, and then calls this function, such that it demonstrates what is not going as expected.

What are the values in the preferences array? Are they all positive? Please also explain how you ran this code in a debugger (setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, ...etc) and point out what the first executed statement was that did something different than expected.

Also tag this question with the programming language you are using.

Why is temp an array? An array with 1 element is basically the same as a regular variable.

Your return; at the end of add_pairs is extraneous.

Holy cow just figured it out, I was missing the = sign for comparison in sort_pairs and it was overlooking the ties! Cannot believe it was so simple.
the return; at the end of add_pairs was already in place in the code excerpt we were given when beginning this project, I could remove it but I just left it there because I didn't put it there and didn't want to mess with the verification check.
I am new to this... It is a struct with a winner and a loser... so I could just say pair temp; and that would create a single instance of pair?

@trincot preferences starts as all 0 (since it's a global array) and record_preferences only increments them, so they must be non-negative.

Barmar, my comment dates from before the edit that was made. My remarks have mostly been answered by that edit.

New to coding as well as this site, sorry for my lack of information and general informality, I'll do better in the future. Cheers.

If you know the explanation and the solution please create your own answer post according to [answer].
